# Geocoding and Animation.drop incompatible with timeout?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I wrote a little html page in order to display pushpins on a map.
I give some address to my webpage, then I use the geocoding() and i display pushpins.

Then, I would like to add the **google.maps.Animation.DROP** with a timeout like explained on the Google Maps API page. ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration?hl=fr)

**On the Google Maps API page, the sample code directly uses the coordinates. It's simple.**

In my case, I need to use before the **geocoding()** to get points, then display the pushpins.

I really don't understand but I'm unable to use this Drop animation with timeout using geocoding. I used the debugger view in Chrome, and I don't understand.

**Here is my code, i tried to do as simple as possible :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAs4c8xnkxcZNRK6yQt-Y21N1L3mT1AFfE&callback=initMap">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"  ></div>

<noscript><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
  However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
  To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
  try again.
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var infoWindow;
var map;
var geocoder;
var bounds; 
var TbCoordonnees       =   [];
var TbMarkers           =   [];
var AdresseTiersTb      =   [];

function initMap() 
{   

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var optionsCarte =  {
                            zoom: 8,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.5, 2.9),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), optionsCarte);

    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    // EXAMPLE :

    AdresseTiersTb.push("39 Boulevard de Courtais, 03100 Montluçon");
    AdresseTiersTb.push("Place de l'Hôtel de ville, 13100 Aix-en-Provence");
    AdresseTiersTb.push("55 Rue du Faubourg Saint-Honoré, 75008 Paris");
    AdresseTiersTb.push("Place des Buisses, 59000 Lille");

    for (var i = 0; i < AdresseTiersTb.length; i++)
    {   
        geocodeAddress(AdresseTiersTb[i],i*200);        
    }

}   

function geocodeAddress(address,timeout)
{
    geocoder.geocode(
    {'address': address},
        function(results, status)
        {
            if((results != null) && (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK))
            {
                var marker = createMarker(address,timeout,results);
            } 
            else 
            {
                alert("geocode failed on "+address+", status="+status);
            }
        }
    );
}

function createMarker(address,timeout,results)
{
    var marker;

    window.setTimeout(function() {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                });},timeout);


    bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
    map.fitBounds(bounds)
    map.panToBounds(bounds); 
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter()); 

    var infocontent = address;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infocontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
}

function listenMarker (marker, info)
{
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(info);
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });
}




</script>
```

The problem is the var **marker** appear to be undefined, so no pushpins once pushpin is displayed instead of three. I don't know why but when I look in debug mode I don't understand how the geocoding is executed. Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a useful value of the `marker` variable from the asynchronous setTimeout callback function (where it is created and added to the map).  The function returns the variable immediately (before it is defined by the callback of the `setTimeout` call (which runs some time later).  The `marker` is also not defined when you are adding the `click` event listener.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y23maud1/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var infoWindow;
var map;
var geocoder;
var bounds;
var TbCoordonnees = [];
var TbMarkers = [];
var AdresseTiersTb = [];

function initMap() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var optionsCarte = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.5, 2.9),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), optionsCarte);
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

  // EXAMPLE :
  AdresseTiersTb.push("Versailles, FR");
  AdresseTiersTb.push("Paris, FR");
  AdresseTiersTb.push("Sens, FR");

  for (var i = 0; i < AdresseTiersTb.length; i++) {
    geocodeAddress(AdresseTiersTb[i], i * 200);
  }
}

function geocodeAddress(address, timeout) {
  // function closure on address.
  geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    },
    function(results, status) {
      if ((results != null) && (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)) {
        createMarker(address, results[0].geometry.location, timeout);
        bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(bounds)
      } else {
        alert("geocode failed on " + address + ", status=" + status);
      }
    }
  );
}

function createMarker(address, latLng, timeout) {
  // function closure on address, latLng
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: latLng,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, address) {
      // function closure on marker, address
      return function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(address);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, address));
  }, timeout);
}

function listenMarker(marker, info) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(info);
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```